# How to set the result's encoding after runing find-dired?

Tags: search, encoding, emacs

[image]

OS info:

```
uname -r
4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64
emacs --version
GNU Emacs 25.1.1
```

More info about emacs:

```
M-x eshell
locale

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I can not find the right answer via google.
How to solve this?

Comment: What version of Emacs are you on? What OS do you use? Does `dired` behave this way too or is it a `find-dired` specific problem?

Comment: Hi @shakurov, I have added my info. It is just a `find-dired` specific problem.

Comment: Please replace the image with text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting this variable:

```el
(setq find-ls-option '("-exec ls -ldh {} +" . "-ldh"))
```

This should workaround the problem.

The actual problem might be with Emacs's terminal encoding, though. Try setting

```el
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
```

and carefully inspecting `LC_ALL`, `LC_CTYPE` and `LANG` environment variables (inside Emacs, of course).

Comment: I've appended your code in my `~/.emacs` file and rebooted emacs, tried find-dired again, but still showing as the image.

Comment: What does saying `locale` in `M-x eshell` produce? While you're at it, try running `find` manually inside eshell (with the `-exec ls -ldh {} +` option). Does that work?

Comment: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: I've tried `find ~/0man/ -exec ls -ldh {} +` in eshell and showing right.

Comment: Showing wrong as the image in eshell after typing `find ~/0man/ -ls`

Comment: Hm... What command does `M-x find-dired` run? (The command should be displayed as the second line in find-dired the result buffer.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136887/discussion-between-shakurov-and-big-shield).